# How are the process.env.NODE_ENV checks removed from ReactJS production builds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs, rollupjs

I know ReactJS converts `__DEV__` into `"production" !== process.env.NODE_ENV` - [like this](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/f2493c0188263fd40d2e456e7567fbee3752fbbf/packages/babel-preset-fbjs/plugins/dev-expression.js#L73-L74). I saw somewhere that it's converted directly to a boolean, depending on the environment, but that's another confusing point.

I was wondering, though, what specific babel-plugin/process/packages actually *removes* this condition from the production React (`react.min.js`), because there are no such conditions in that file.

From my understanding, it's a two-step process:

1. using a Babel plugin, convert warnings and invariant calls into `if
   ("production" !== process.env.NODE_ENV)` calls
2. remove the
   entire above conditions (or just its truthy branch?) in the production build, when minifying

How/where is the latter implemented?

Comment: @EmileBergeron If I interpret the question correctly, it is about how *Facebook* removes `process.env.NODE_ENV` checks from React's production builds

Comment: The term you are looking for is [envify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envify). That is, a process goes into your code and _actually replaces_ your `process.env.var` expressions with its literal replacement. Then, when your code goes through minification, it removes anything that will always be true or false. There are other libraries for this too, such as [loose-envify](https://github.com/zertosh/loose-envify).

Comment: `it removes anything that will always be true or false`. Did you mean `it removes anything that will always be false`? In case it's always `true`, I think it only removes the _condition_. Cf. [DefinePlugin page](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ReactJS uses Webpack to bundle its production code.
Webpack has a plugin called [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), which ReactJS [uses](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3d8b836e22981063d0396e04eefcb10fdec600ee/fixtures/packaging/webpack/prod/config.js#L12-L17). This plugin replaces literal values in the code, values that you can control. Very similar to compiler inlining.

*Either I don't get the name of this plugin, or it's just a poor choice. In my research trying to find out how ReactJS cleans up its production code, I've more than once skimmed over the `new webpack.DefinePlugin()` call. Also, my lack of experience with Webpack didn't help.*

---

As mentioned in the [plugin page](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) it's a multi-step process:

**1. Original code**:

```
if (!PRODUCTION) {
  console.log('Debug info');
}

if (PRODUCTION) {
  console.log('Production log');
}
```

**2. Inlining done by the Define plugin**:

```
if (!true) {
  console.log('Debug info');
}
if (true) {
  console.log('Production log');
}
```

**3. Minification step, and the final result**

```
console.log('Production log');
```

---

The minification/optimization step is done through a tool called [Terser](https://github.com/terser-js/terser), which is what Webpack is [using](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/). Terser looks like [a fork of UglifyJS](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/311a7285d36b38bada46102967c431e93ff48a89), and it, too, [has the ability to remove dead code](https://github.com/terser-js/terser#compress-options).

So it's:

1. ReactJS compile production
2. React configures Webpack with `DefinePlugin process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'`
3. Webpack inlining, done by the Webpack's `DefinePlugin`
4. Webpack optimizing
5. Webpack Terser plugin
6. Terser finally removes dead code

I'd like to thank @romellem for pointing me in the right direction through this jungle.

PS: Dear future readers, I've written this in the 10th of May 2019. My findings are probably going to be obsolete soon.

Answer (score 3):

The code is removed when the JS is uglified (minified).

[UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) has an option  [`dead_code`](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compress-options) that "*remove[s] unreachable code.*"

As to *how* this works, the logic here is fairly complex, but a starting point would be Uglify's [`eliminate_dead_code` function](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/blob/5476cb8f/lib/compress.js#L1917).